# logrotate not rotating the logs

Tags: logrotate

I have this logrotate config and I am running on Ubuntu 10.04.

```
/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log {
    daily
    rotate 3
    compress
    notifempty
    missingok
    create 660 mysql adm
    postrotate 
    if test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin && \
       /usr/bin/mysqladmin  ping &>/dev/null
    then
       /usr/bin/mysqladmin  flush-logs
    fi
endscript
```

}

I put this in /etc/logrotate.d yesterday and today the log was not rotated.

Below are the things that I have done:

1. I verified that the log is indeed in /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
2. mysqladmin lines work fine when run as root
3. mysql is able to write to the mysql-slow.log

When I did this:

```
$ logrotate -d -f mysql-slow

reading config file mysql-slow
reading config info for /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log 

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log  forced from command line (3 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log, log->rotateCount is 3
dateext suffix '-20120329'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.3.gz to /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.4.gz     (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 3), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.2.gz to /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.3.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.1.gz to /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.2.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.0.gz to /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.1.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 0), 
renaming /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log to /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.1
creating new /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log mode = 0660 uid = 20004 gid = 4
running postrotate script
running script (multiple) with arg /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log : " 
    if test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin && \
       /usr/bin/mysqladmin &>/dev/null
    then
       /usr/bin/mysqladmin flush-logs
    fi
"
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
removing old log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.4.gz
```

1. Where is the log that shows that logrotate was successful? I want to see if there is anything that would say that there was a problem.
2. Any ideas on why the logrotate is not working?

Comment: So it does work when executed by hand?  Is `crond` running?

Comment: yes it works, if you mean logrotate -f mysql_slow_query. And crond is running.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another config already that is supposed to handle that log file?  Perhaps `mysql-server`?  Run `grep '/var/log/mysql' /etc/logrotate.d/*`.

Comment: I ran that command and only my config show up as doing something in /var/log/mysql

Comment: At what time of the day do the daily cron jobs run in your Ubuntu setup? You may find that information in the `/etc/crontab` file, in the line that ends with `/etc/cron.daily )`. Maybe you created the logrotate config after the cron daily jobs for that day had already run?

Comment: Thanks. I check /etc/crontab and it runs at 6:25 am on a daily. I added the logrotate before that.

Comment: Is there a file that logs the output of logrotate?

Comment: Try disabling compression to see if it runs this way. If it does, you might need to setup a /root/.my.cnf

Answer (score 70):

A common issue is when you first setup a daily logrotate.d entry, it will not rotate the first day.  When you use a time based rotation (daily/weekly/monthly) logrotate scribbles a date stamp of the last date it saw the file in `/var/lib/logrotate/status` (or `/var/lib/logrotate.status` on RHEL systems).

The scribbled date becomes the reference date from that future runs of `logrotate` will use to compare 'daily' rotations.  Since the default cron job runs daily, this is typically only a problem in daily jobs.

You can avoid this problem two ways;

1. run `sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/<my rotate job>`

   - This will scribble the date into the status file and rotate the logs
2. Edit `/var/lib/logrotate/status` and add the line manually:

   `"/var/log/my_special.log"  2013-4-8`

   - setting it to today's or a prior date. Next run should cause it to run.

Comment: Works like a champ!

Comment: Actually it **does** rotate the logs when using `-f` (at least on my RH derivative).

Comment: `-f` for Force Rotation, `-d` for Debug, also debug implies dry run so no changes will actually be made while `-d` is on.

Comment: `-d` implying dry run is a tricky one. No changes were being made, and had me scratching my head until I realized this fact.

Answer (score 6):

According to the following Slicehost article:

**Understanding logrotate on Ubuntu - part 2**
http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/30/understanding-logrotate-on-ubuntu-part-2

... the `/var/lib/logrotate/status` file "*stores information about when it last rotated each log file.*". The [logrotate manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/logrotate.8.html) says that is called a "state file".

There's another discussion here in ServerFault that may also be useful:

[How does logrotate exactly handle "daily"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/198203/how-does-logrotate-exactly-handle-daily)

In that discussion, "MadHatter" says the following, regarding the "status" (state) file:

> " Each file has one line, which is the date on which it was last rotated; if you run logrotate on such a date that a given file is due for rotation, given the number of days between current date and the date in the file (1 for daily, 7 for weekly, etc.), the file will be rotated. "

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If `mysqladmin` requires a user or password it will not read it from `/root/.my.cnf` configuration without modification.

Try piping your output to logger to see what is happening.

```
  postrotate
      # just if mysqld is really running
      if test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin && \
         /usr/bin/mysqladmin ping &>/dev/null
      then
         env HOME=/root/ /usr/bin/mysqladmin flush-logs 2>&1 | logger
      else
         logger "mysqladmin ping failed so not rotating mysql logs"
      fi
  endscript
```

[MySQL doesn't logs error to new file after rotating?](https://serverfault.com/questions/415774/mysql-doesnt-logs-error-to-new-file-after-rotating)

Comment: On Debian installed db servers you might want to make sure you have valid credentials in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf as the default logrotate script that comes with the package by default will try to use the debian-sys-maint user as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the logrotate output for the word "error". It seems logrotate skips some tasks (but not all tasks) when it encounters errors.

For example, under Debian/Ubuntu, you can run:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf --verbose --force |& grep -i '[^-_/.]error'
```

The regexp is to avoid listing files that contain the word "error". The ampersand is to also redirect stderr to grep (according to the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) ) :

> `|&` has been added to Bash 4 as an abbreviation for 2>&1 |

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on CentOS where my weekly log backups were not running.  The problem ended up being someone removing the execute permissions on the /etc/cron.daily/0anacron file.  Changed permissions back to 755 and it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 20.04, logrotate 3.11.0) forcing logrotate to run (using -f) helped finding the cause of the thing not working (in spite of messages in syslog that confusingly appeared to show otherwise).
Forcing the run prompted the error:

> error: skipping ... because parent directory has insecure permissions

Adding a line noting the rightful owners of the parent directory:

> su somegroup someuser

in my /etc/logrotate.d/ config file solved the problem.