# MySQL doesn't logs error to new file after rotating?

Tags: mysql, logrotate

Problem solved but I'm writing down for the future reference.

**`/root/.my.cnf`**

```
[mysqladmin]
user            = root
password        = pa$$w0rd
```

**`/etc/logrotate.d/mysql`**

```
/var/log/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysqld.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    dateext
    compress
    missingok
    #notifempty
    sharedscripts
    create 644 mysql mysql
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/mysqladmin flush-logs
    endscript
}
```

`logrotate` is working fine when running from the command line:

```
# logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.d/mysql
```

but it doesn't work when running from cron at 4 A.M. The logs file was rotated but MySQL doesn't logs the error to newly created file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql      0 Aug  7 10:13 /var/log/mysqld.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql     20 Aug  4 04:04 /var/log/mysqld.log-20120804.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql     20 Aug  5 04:04 /var/log/mysqld.log-20120805.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql     20 Aug  6 16:28 /var/log/mysqld.log-20120806.gz
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the `postrotate`, I redirect both stderr and stdout to a log file to see what happens:

```
postrotate
    /usr/bin/mysqladmin flush-logs > /var/log/mysqladmin.flush-logs 2>&1
endscript
```

What I get is:

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

It sounds like `mysqladmin` doesn't read `/root/.my.cnf` during logrotate.

So, try this:

```
postrotate
    env HOME=/root/ /usr/bin/mysqladmin flush-logs > /var/log/mysqladmin.flush-logs 2>&1
endscript
```

Source:

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=51005
- http://scribble.scran.ac.uk/svene/weblog/2893.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

I didn't restart MySQL after adding `/root/.my.cnf`, so the postrotate flush command wasn't run.

Once I restarted MySQL it read the root my.cnf file and worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the block in `/etc/logrotate.d/mysql` looked a bit different:

```
postrotate
        test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin || exit 0

        if [ -f `my_print_defaults --mysqld | grep -oP "pid-file=\K[^$]+"` ]; then
            # If this fails, check debian.conf!
            mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf flush-logs
        fi
endscript
```

Note the comment: "If this fails, check debian.conf!" and the command having the parameter `--defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`. This file had the very same `[client]` section, defining user `root` with an empty password. So obviously, the very same password used in `/root/.my.cnf` had to be placed in that file as well. Security-wise, `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` is similar to `/root/.my.cnf`: owned by `root:root`, and chmodded to `0600`.

Answer (score 0):

So, In my case, There's a permission problem to `debian-sys-maint` user, because of, the `galera-cluster` has the same integrity on each node, although, each node install individually, by the debian user for each one, which, the config file is `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

So in the `logrotate` file is:

```
postrotate
    test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin || exit 0
    if [ -f `my_print_defaults --mysqld | grep -oP "pid-file=\K[^$]+"` ]; then
        # If this fails, check debian.conf!
        mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --local flush-error-log \
          flush-engine-log flush-general-log flush-slow-log
    fi
endscript
```

The solution so simple, just, change the password of `debian-sys-maint` user on one node, and set the password on the '/etc/mysql/debian.cnf' file on every nodes

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' = password('YOUR PASSWORD');
```

I hope, it be useful, as mine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I need have been set `--defaults-file="/root/.my.cnf"` to `/root/.my.cnf` in `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file="/root/.my.cnf" ping` and `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file="/root/.my.cnf" flush-logs`

/etc/logrotate.d/mysql

```
/var/log/mysql/mysql_general_log.log
/var/log/mysql/error.log {
        create 600 mysql mysql
        notifempty
        daily
        rotate 5
        missingok
        compress
    postrotate
    # just if mysqld is really running
    if test -x /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin && \
        /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file="/root/.my.cnf" ping &>/dev/null
    then
        /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file="/root/.my.cnf" flush-logs
    fi
    endscript
}
```

My `/root/.my.cnf` have

`-rw-------  1 root root   43 Mar 21 20:51 .my.cnf`

```
[mysqladmin]
password= 111
user= root
```